How to correctly configure OAuth 2.0 - Authorization Code with PKCE flow in Azure?
I'm trying to use OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code with PKCE flow in Postman and then in my flutter mobile application which will work on both Android and iOS systems. OAuth 2.0 is configured in Azure, on the application level.
I'm using myapp://logged-in redirect URL to read the access token from the callback. Because the redirect URL is configured for Mobile/Native platform, the application itself is set as public.

Unfortunately the authorization is not working. When I try to request the token with PKCE flow, I'm getting following error. It is casued by the public setting in the app registration.

Error: invalid_client, Description: AADSTS700025: Client is public so
neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented.

When I remove client_secret from the request, Postman throws

Error: invalid_request, Description: AADSTS900144: The request body
must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'.


Based on the below articles:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67097711/7586834
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63124656
I should be able to retrieve the token without passing the ClientSecret. For now, as workaround I'm using Implicit flow and it is working correctly. But since it is obsolete, I want to switch to newest flow. What/how should I change to make it working?
(manifest file from my app)
<intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth_2">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myapp" /> 
</intent-filter>

Ps. I'm using flutter https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth_2 package.

If public client flows option is enabled, you cannot pass client secret while generating token. Could you confirm whether it is asking to login or not when client secret is removed?

With PKCE flow you must not pass the client secret. Pass the client ID instead. Show your Dart code.

Hi @Redzix Any update?

I registered one application and added redirect URI in "Mobile and desktop applications" platform by enabling public client flow option:

Note that, you cannot pass client secret with PKCE flow when public client flow option is enabled. Otherwise, it will throw below error:

When I removed the client secret and tried to generate the token using PKCE flow with same Postman config, I too got same error like this:
Configuration:

Error:

To resolve the error, change Client Authentication method to "Send client credentials in body" that generated the token successfully like this:
Configuration:

Token:

When I decoded above token in jwt.ms website, it has below claims:

